# Menu region showing up inappropriately

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am trying to customize a wordpress theme. In header.php it checks if a menu exists in a certain region and if there isnt one it is supposed to not show anything. However the region is still showing up even though there is no menu there. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

```
<nav id="resurrect-header-menu" class="resurrect-clearfix">
  <div id="resurrect-header-menu-inner" class="resurrect-clearfix">
    <?php
      wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'header',
                    'menu_id'           => 'resurrect-header-menu-links',
                    'menu_class'        => 'sf-menu',
                    'container'         => false, // don't wrap in div
                    'fallback_cb'       => false, // don't show pages if no menu found - show nothing
                    'walker'            => new CTFW_Walker_Nav_Menu_Description
                 ) );
    ?>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it please.

`<div id="resurrect-header-menu-inner" class="resurrect-clearfix">`

```js
 function toggle_visibility(news) {
       var e = document.getElementById(news);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility

('menu');">Menu</a>
 <span id="menu" style="display:none;color: 

#00ccff;"> 
<a href="">remove me 1</a><br>
<a href="">remove me 2</a><br>
Put here your php code...
</span>
```